# Showing if $G$ is Abelian and two elements in $G$ are of finite order, then their product is of finite order.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Show that if $G$ is an abelian group and $a,b \in G$ both have finite order, then so does the element $ab$.

I have a solution, but I want to verify if my solution makes sense.

Let $a, b \in G$ such that $ab = ba$ i.e. $G$ is abelian. There is some $a^m$ = $e$ and $b^n$ = $e$ where $m,n$ $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$.

We want to show that $ab = ba$ has a finite order.

Thus $(ab)^{mn} = (a)^{mn}(b)^{mn} = (a^m)^n(b^n)^m = (e)^n(e)^m = e$.

Since $(ab)^{mn} = e = (ba)^{mn}$ since $G$ is abelian. So $ab$ has finite order.

Comment: This is fine provided that you’ve already proved that if $ab=ba$, then $(ab)^k=a^kb^k$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. If not, you need to prove that fact; it’s an easy induction argument.

Comment: That is correct. You can even write down the order of $ab$ in terms of those of $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is perfect. Now be careful, the place you used that $G$ was abelian was to say that $(ab)^{mn}=a^{mn}b^{mn}$; this is not true for a general group.

Comment: Awesome, and yes I know. :P